# Pushing items from first array of objects to another array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

```
defaultParameterTypes = [] // this is my empty array



const propsArray = this.props.device.deviceProperties.defaultParameterTypes;      
 const defaultParameterTypes = this.state.deviceSettings.defaultParameterTypes;
```

when i checked on checkbox i want to push into my defaultParameterTypes array the object but the case is 
 when the type is repeated dont push it twice.

```
"propsArray": "[{'name': '1','type': '11'}, {'name': '2','type': '22'}, {'name': '3','type': '11'}, {'name': '4','type': '11'}, {'name': '5','type': '22'}, {'name': '6','type': '22'}, {'name': '7','type': '22'}]",
```

i want to make like loop and check if it is not found in `defaultEmptyArray` and push it if not found 
but i dont need the type to be repeated in `mydefaultarray`

Comment: So have you made the loop to check to push elements or not? Update your question with your attempt and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: i dont know how to make it

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < propsArray.length; i++) {
            if (e.target.checked) {
                if (propsArray[i].type === defaultParameterTypes[j].type) {
                        alert("Dont Push this type")
                        // break;
                    }
                    else {
                            alert("Push this type");
                            defaultParameterTypes.push(propsArray[i]);
                            // break;
                         }

            }}

Comment: i was trying like this but i need to make like to check if it is found in defaultParameterTypes or not

Comment: What is your expected result? If type seen again, don't copy, or only maintain one copy overall, i.e. overwrite it each time so the last one seen is what remains?

Comment: All things work good but my problem is in this for loop and if else how to check if this not found in another and push it if not found

Comment: yes exactly if type seen again dont push the object again

Answer (score 1):

Simple way would be to create a map of the types seen in the array and reduce your input array into it, then get the array of values from the map you created.

```js
const data = [
  { name: "1", type: "11" },
  { name: "2", type: "22" },
  { name: "3", type: "11" },
  { name: "4", type: "11" },
  { name: "5", type: "22" },
  { name: "6", type: "22" },
  { name: "7", type: "22" }
];

// reduce array into map of type => { name, type }
// then get the object values array
const reducedData = Object.values(
  data.reduce((acc, { name, type}) => {
    if (!acc[type]) acc[type] = { name, type }; // if not seen type, store
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(reducedData)
```

Expand on this concept to create a function that takes two arrays and processes the second into the first.

```js
const data = [
  { name: "1", type: "11" },
  { name: "2", type: "22" },
  { name: "3", type: "44" },
  { name: "4", type: "11" },
  { name: "5", type: "22" },
  { name: "6", type: "33" },
  { name: "7", type: "22" }
];

const data2 = [
  { name: "1", type: "33" },
  { name: "2", type: "22" },
  { name: "3", type: "66" },
  { name: "4", type: "11" },
  { name: "5", type: "22" },
  { name: "6", type: "44" },
  { name: "7", type: "22" }
];

const data3 = [
  { name: "1", type: "66" },
  { name: "2", type: "22" },
  { name: "3", type: "33" },
  { name: "4", type: "11" },
  { name: "5", type: "55" },
  { name: "6", type: "11" },
  { name: "7", type: "44" }
];

const reduceData = (currentArray = [], newArray = []) => {
  const mapFn = (acc, { name, type }) => {
    if (!acc[type]) acc[type] = { name, type }; // if not seen type, store
    return acc;
  };
  const createMap = array => array.reduce(mapFn, {});

  return Object.values(newArray.reduce(mapFn, createMap(currentArray)));
};

const reducedData = reduceData(data, data2);
const reducedData1 = reduceData(reducedData, data3);

console.log(reducedData);
console.log(reducedData1);
```

Comment: but i need one more thing in same issue

Comment: i want to compare the 2 arrays the default and the props array

Comment: ( i want to compare only the type of the object) that if first item in propsArray is not fount in defaultParameterTypes array then push the object to defaultParameterTypes

Comment: Thanks alot Mr. Drew

Comment: But the first is better

Comment: the second example is not like my example

Comment: i am working with react js and i want to push into my empty array but first i want to check if something is found in it or not.

Comment: first i need to compare like i send you the for loop that i want to check if the first element in the propsArray is found in the defaultArray and if not push it , until the loop ends when going through all the elements of propsArray (and checking only the type if it is found or not and not the whole object but pushing the object not only the type )

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but from what you describe the second snippet does exactly that. It first builds a map of the "existing" initial array values so it can then check against when "merging" in a new array. In your case your state array value is the "currentArray" value, and the props array is the "newArray" value. If this is not what you are expecting then please update your question and specify what your expected output should be.

Comment: The new array is defaultParameterTypes and the propsArray is the full api array. First i want to select a cheboxes like the example and when select i want to push in the defaultParameter array which is empty by default. After that when i select i want to check if the type of this selected object is found in the defaultParameterTypes or not . Then if the type is found in the defaultParameterTypes array i cant push the object that includes(name, type)  again and if a new type is found i can push the object that includes  (name and type).

Comment: So at last i will have that defaultParameterTypes array is only have one unique type 
 of each object with its name. example [{'1', '11'},{'2','22'},{'3','33}] tis is true like this.The wrong example like i have in the array after pushing like that: [[{'1', '11'},{'2','11'},{'3','33}] ] because i have same type twice pushed into defaultParameterTypes array. so when i select i want to check if the type is found before i push the object

Comment: @Abbass Did you try running the code snippets I provided. As far as I can tell, my second snippet does exactly as you describe. Please try it, it disallows duplicate `type` keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
let hasValue = (arr, obj) => arr && arr.filter(item => item.type == obj.type).length

let result = propsArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 if (hasValue(acc, curr)) {
  return acc;
 } else {
  return [...acc, curr]
 }
}, []);
```

will give u an array with all the elements where the type property is unique..

hope this is what ur expected result..

```
let result = propsArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 if (hasValue(acc, curr)) {
  return [...acc, { name: curr.name }];
 } else {
  return [...acc, curr]
 }
}, []);
```

or if type reccurs, copy only the name object..

this will return an array of same length but along the elements, type property will be removed if it recurrs...

Comment: if you please send me your email to contact you and send you the screenshot and what i am facing

Comment: and really thank you very much you helped me to think more when you send your examples

Comment: if (checked) {
                defaultParameterTypes.push({ "name": e.target.name, "type": e.target.value })
                this.setState({
                    deviceSettings: {
                        ...this.state.deviceSettings,
                        defaultParameterTypes
                    }
                });
                }

Comment: else {
                    let defaultParameterTypes = this.state.deviceSettings.defaultParameterTypes;
                    const i = defaultParameterTypes.findIndex(
                        item => item.type === e.target.value
                    );
                    defaultParameterTypes = defaultParameterTypes.slice(0, i).concat(
                        defaultParameterTypes.slice(i + 1, defaultParameterTypes.length)
                    );

Comment: this.setState({
                        deviceSettings: {
                            ...this.state.deviceSettings,
                            defaultParameterTypes
                    }
                })
            }

Comment: how can i check if type exist and if not will push the object that contains name and type

Comment: dude, first u update ur question with necessary code. people will simply vote u down if u ask without taking any effort or necessary code.... u don't know because u r new to stack overflow. once u build some reputation, u should be extra carefull. 1) explain ur requirement. 2) show necessary code 3) explain ur effort and where u stuck on. don't take me wrong, this is how stackoverflow works.

Comment: hi bro, okay yes i am new to stackoverflow and i will repeat my question in a good way